# Read a text file line by line in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

How can I read a text file line by line in Qt?

I'm looking for the Qt equivalent to:

```
std::ifstream infile;
std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Use this code:

```
QFile inputFile(fileName);
if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
   QTextStream in(&inputFile);
   while (!in.atEnd())
   {
      QString line = in.readLine();
      ...
   }
   inputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: shouldn't mode be `(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)` ?

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov QIODevice::Text is the default.

Comment: @Sergio: Just for curiosity,if the input file contains comma separated string then how to parse

Comment: @Chinmoy Use the QString split() method.

Comment: @sashoalm how it's default? "By default, QFile assumes binary, i.e. it doesn't perform any conversion on the bytes stored in the file." - Qt docs....

Comment: How do I specify the linefeed char? In my case, there are only \r, no \n.

Answer (score 8):

This code might be a little simpler:

```
QFile inputFile(QString("/path/to/file"));
inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
if (!inputFile.isOpen())
    return;

QTextStream stream(&inputFile);
for (QString line = stream.readLine();
     !line.isNull();
     line = stream.readLine()) {
    /* process information */
};
```

Comment: answers with just code snippets are not very helpful.

Comment: Your code snippet was helpful. `(!line.isNull())` was what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

Since Qt 5.5 you can use `QTextStream::readLineInto`. It behaves similar to `std::getline` and is maybe faster as `QTextStream::readLine`, because it reuses the string:

```
QIODevice* device;
QTextStream in(&device);

QString line;
while (in.readLineInto(&line)) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example from my code. So I will read a text from 1st line to 3rd line using readLine() and then store to array variable and print into textfield using for-loop :

```
QFile file("file.txt");

    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return;

    QTextStream in(&file);
    QString line[3] = in.readLine();
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        ui->textEdit->append(line[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this, for *read* from file:

**The included lib:**

```
#include "QFile"
#include "QDir"
```

**The Code:**

```
QFile file;
file.setFileName("text.txt");
QDir::setCurrent("C:/Users/USER_NAME/Documents/QTCreatorWorkspace/untitled1");
QTextStream data(&file);

if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
    ui->plainTextEdit->insertPlainText(file.readAll());
    file.close();
}
else{
    //Error statement
}
```

And for *write* to file:
**The Code:**

```
QFile file;
file.setFileName("text.txt");
QDir::setCurrent("C:/Users/USER_NAME/Documents/QTCreatorWorkspace/untitled1");
QTextStream data(&file);

if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){
    data << ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText();
    file.close();
}
```