# Qt: Linking my model data with a QListView

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing my first Qt project (so I'm new to the environment) and I've got this project build using the MVC design pattern.
It's a pretty basic note manager/editor. I've got a class uiman ("Ui Manager") which takes care of my UI, and my function to open a notes database (which is just a list of text files to open)

```
void uiman::openDBDialog(){

    QFileDialog dialog;
    dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
    dialog.setDirectory("/Users/myuserdir/Desktop");
    dialog.setFilter(QDir::Files);
    dialog.setWindowTitle("Open File");
    dialog.setNameFilter("Textie Notes DB(*.db)");
    dialog.exec();
    QString pathDB = dialog.selectedFiles().first();

    model = new notesModel();
    model->setNotesDB(new QString(pathDB.toUtf8().constData()));
    refreshAll();
}
```

so far, so good. I take the path of my database and give it to my model, which should now manage the rest.
Now, the `refreshAll()` function should take the list I opened up and show them in my QListView, but I can't parse the file and append items on the go using `clear()` and `append()` unlike the QListWidget. So, how do I approach building a vector (I suppose) of names from my file and feeding them to my QListView?

Sorry if I'm not being clear, but the official documentation hasn't been clear enough.

Edit: This is my model, nodesmodel, and here's the code.

```
notesModel::notesModel(QObject *parent) :
    QFileSystemModel(parent)
{
    QStringList noteList;

}


void notesModel::setNotesDB(QString *dbpath){
    // open the notes database
    databasepath = dbpath;

}

QFile* notesModel::getDB(){
    if(this->dbFile == NULL)
        this->dbFile = new QFile(databasepath-    >toUtf8().constData());
    return this->dbFile;
}
```

Comment: what is model? and whats in the function notesModel()?

Comment: Can you please edit the post with details of notesModel.. In the comment they are unreadable.

Comment: Sorry, I had problems with formatting, fixed in the main question.

Comment: Please check if this link helps : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#using-models-and-views

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, you do not add/remove data from the viewer widget itself, this is done in the model.

You can set the model with the setModel() method.

If you want to show a simple QString list, then you can use:

```
QStringList strings;
strings << "String 1" << "String 2" << "String 3";
model = new QStringListModel(strings, parent);
view->setModel(model);
// model is managed by parent, and will be deleted when parent is deleted.
// If you create multiple models you might consider other memory management strategy
```

To read a text file and store its lines in a QStringList, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445381/18403) answer.

Comment: Ok, but I have to feed my QStringList with the list read from the file. How do I convert my data to a QStringList?

Comment: This question was already asked here, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5445381/18403).

Comment: Thank you so much, but the compiler fails at "model" (line 3 and 4 in your code) , because it says it's an undeclared identifier (view is also undeclared). Should I instantiate them in some way?

Comment: You probably should declare the model as a member, but if you want to just do a quick test: QStringListModel model = new QStringListModel(strings,parent);

Comment: That line of code brings a "reference to non-static member function must be called". It looks like he doesn't like the "parent".

Comment: 'parent' is the parent QObject that will manage the memory of the model (will delete it when itself is deleted). If you are inside a 'mainwindow', pass 'this' as the parent.

Comment: I'm inside my "notesmodel" class. Should I pass my mainwindow to the model? Does this will keep the MVC relationship? I mean, the model should not talk directly to the view, right?

Comment: Any QObject* can be the parent. NotesModel can be one too.