# How to open/close file at a specific entry in Qt5

Tags: c++, io, qt5

I'm making a program that needs to be able to edit files at specific points, specific lines won't do since the line count will change over time. I plan to do this with qt's textEdit menu element.

So for example lets say I have a file that has a comment somewhere in it like so:

```
#qtread
lots
of
stuff
#qtend
```

Is there any way I can make a Qt text edit open the file and edit only whatever is between the **#qtread** and **#qtend** entries?

(Also I am a total beginner to Qt, so an idiotproof answer would be superb, thanks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read your file line by line like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444959/read-a-text-file-line-by-line-in-qt). Create a `bool` indicating whether to read e.g. `readEnabled`. After you've read the line, check for your tokens:

```
QFile inputFile(fileName);
QString outputText, startToken = "#qtread", endToken = "#qtend";

if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QTextStream in(&inputFile);
    bool readEnabled = false;

    while (!in.atEnd())
    {
        QString line = in.readLine();

        if(line == endToken) // the whole line has to match your comment
            readEnabled = false;

        if(readEnabled)
            outputText.append(line + "\n");

        if(line == startToken)
            readEnabled = true;
    }

    inputFile.close();
}
```

You might want to refine that. In case you want to start reading right after the comment or accept the comment with trailing whitespaces, see `QString::left`, `QString::mid`, `QString::right` and try to put something together.

**Edit:**

Sorry, I overlooked that you also wanted to save it back. Writing the file is actually a lot harder in this case and I'd do it with the C++ standard library. I encourage you to search for that, post a new question without **qt** flag.

Comment: That code looks like it should work, but for some reason it's not for me, the Output will become the entire file. Here's my code for testing this:

http://pastebin.com/sxbyb6QJ

And here are the contents of the file: http://pastebin.com/qrdCnGgS

In both my while loops, **Output** will become the contents of the entire file from start to finish.

Edit: I will separate those questions then.

Comment: Why did you change `if(readEnabled)` to `if(readEnabled = true)` ?

Comment: By mistake :/ I fixed that and now it works great, thank you!

Comment: That's why I don't write `== true` explicitly :)