# codes to search within a txt file using QT with c++

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on a school project right now, and I need to build a Student Management System with QT. I have a txt file with student information listed in a line like:

```
Studentname accountpassword  studentid
```

Every time a user(student) input their studentname and password, I have to check if the name and password are in the database (which is the txt file right now).

This is what I am struggling with right now. I don't know how I can only search line by line. For example, if the first student user name is jack, and his password is 123456; At the same time, second student user name is peter, and his password is 23567.

How can I check if the username jack and 123456 are inputted at the same time?

```
void MainWindow::on_loginpush_clicked()
{
    QString username = ui -> lineedit_username -> text();
    QString password = ui -> lineedit_password -> text();

    if (username == "admin" && password =="admin")
    {
        Adminmanagment adminview;
        adminview.exec();
    }

    else if( (username != "admin") && (password !="admin"))
        {
            ifstream studentinfo("student.txt");
            if (!studentinfo.is_open())
            {

            }
            else 
            {
                string current_name;
                string current_password;
                string id;
                int numofcourses;
                int gpa;
                char newline;
                char space;
                bool valid =false;
                while((studentinfo>>current_name>>current_password>>id>>numofcourses>>gpa>>noskipws>>newline) &&newline == '\n')
                {   
                    if((current_name == username)&& (current_password== password))
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
}
```

My student.txt looks exactly like below

name  password  id  number of courses  gpa

```
jack 123456 900440123 4 0
testing 987654 900542015 4 2
testing2 8888 900145265 4 2
testing3 8888 900158256 4 0
```

Comment: You need to look at using std::getline and also string tokenisation.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for answering and I will check it out right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested. Expects every line (including last line) ending with a newline character. Given you have 2 QStrings `username` and `password`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>  // std::isspace()

// ...

std::istream& eat_whitespace(std::istream &is) // eats whitespace except '\n'
{
    int ch;
    while (is && (ch = is.peek()) != EOF && ch != '\n'
           && std::isspace(static_cast<char unsigned>(ch)))
    {
        is.get();
    }
    return is;
}

// ...

std::ifstream studentinfo{ "your_file" };
if (!studentinfo.is_open())
    // big trouble

std::string current_name;
std::string current_password;
std::string id;
int numofcourses;
int gpa;
char newline;
bool valid = false;

while ((studentinfo >> current_name >> current_password >> id >> numofcourses >> gpa
                    >> eat_whitespace >> std::noskipws >> newline >> std::skipws )
       && newline == '\n')
{
    if (current_name == username.toLocal8Bit().constData() &&
        current_password == password.toLocal8Bit().constData())
    {
        valid = true;
        break;
    }
}

// valid now true if credentials found.
```

Comment: This is my first time using QT and c++ in the same time, so I am a bit confused. 
I know this will work in a typical cpp file, but for some reason it has a lot error when I create a cpp file and input all these codes into it.  Can you guys please tell me why codes in QT is different than the codes in vs?

Comment: @Stefan You realize that my answer only shows the principle? C++ is no different with or without Qt. If you show what you tried and which errors you get it would be possible to assist you. You could edit your question to contain the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you for all your help sir. I just edited my question with the partial code that I have question with. 
So basically I have two QLineEdit to collect user's input on username and password, and I hope to check if the inputs matching the username and pw in my txt file.
The error I have now is I used QString to collect the username and password, and the program does not let me to compare QString and String.

Comment: something called 
Semantic Issue
 
59:38: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__cxx11::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') and 'QString')

It has a long list of detail. If you need them too, please let me know.

Comment: Oh my god it worked!  However, there is another problem. Lets say I enter the first set of username and password (they are in the first line of my txt file,) and the code works fine. When I enter the second set of username and password (they are in the second line of my txt file,) the program does not work correctly. It just does not recognizing the ac and pw.  @Swordfish

Comment: @Stefan I noticed that you changed the variables to read in the code in your question. Are you sure it matches? I changed my answer accordingly. Also, is the current 2nd line the last line of the file?

Comment: Yes I believe they are matched  because it has no problem with the first line.  And yes, the 2nd line is currently the last line of the file. Should I try adding one more line? @Swordfish

Comment: @Stefan Make sure you open your file in an editor and press [Enter] at the end of the last line ;)

Comment: It did not work. :( I tried adding an new line by using editor, and I pressed the enter key at the end of every line.  @Swordfish

Comment: @Stefan UUps, sorry, I forgot to add another `>> std::skipws`. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks! now it works for the second line too! However, it is not working  correctly again after the second line..  :(  @Swordfish

Comment: @Stefan To stop the guesswork, could you please include a real `student.txt` in your question?

Comment: Yes sir. I don't know how to attach a txt file here, so I typed those four lines I have in my txt file in my question above. Can you please take a look at it?   Also, please ignore those empty lines between the data. There are no double spaces between data in my txt file. @Swordfish

Comment: @Stefan No, but I bet there is a space right before the newline of line 3 ;) Edited my answer to ignore whitespace at the end of a line.

Comment: Oh my god.. I don't know what is happening.  I copied your code to my program, and it works for the third line now. However, it does not work on the last line again..   :(  @Swordfish

Comment: @Stefan Is there a newline at the end of the last line ;)

Comment: I think there is no newline at the end of the last line..  I tried deleting and there was nothing in there.   @Swordfish

Comment: @Stefan Then you got me wrong: Please make sure there IS a newline at the end of the last line.

Comment: Oh! I added a newline at the end, and it works fine now!  Thank you sir. You are my savior. @Swordfish

Comment: Thank you again. I hope you are having a great thanksgiving holiday. @Swordfish

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are using Qt. This question shows how to read a file line by line([Read a text file line by line in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444959/read-a-text-file-line-by-line-in-qt)) with Qfile.

You could then use QStrings in built equality operators to see if they’re the same. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html